# Variance of exponential moving average

Tags: statistics, recursion, average, standard-deviation, time-series

I'm not quite sure what the form for the rolling recursive variance should look like. I have that the recursive average is $m_t = \alpha x_t +(1-a)m_{t-1}$. Then would the rolling recursive variance be $V_t = \alpha (x_t-m_t)^2 +(1-\alpha)V_{t-1}^2$ or  $V_t = \alpha (x_t-m_t)^2 +(1-\alpha)V_{t-1}$?